# Placing a structure into memory smaller than it

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer, bit-fields, strict-aliasing

I'm optimizing a compression algorithm, which uses a structure that spans 2 bytes.  But there are times when I'd like it to interpret just 1 byte, as its members that (I expect) to map onto the 2nd byte are never written or read.

Do I have any guarantee that the compiler will not access the 2nd byte so long as `zFmt` and `wFmt` are never accessed?  If not, can I compose a static assertion that will stop compilation when this assumption is wrong?

```cpp
struct Header {
    uint8_t xFmt : 4;
    uint8_t yFmt : 4;
    uint8_t zFmt : 4; // must not be read/written when header is mapped to 1 byte
    uint8_t wFmt : 4; // must not be read/written when header is mapped to 1 byte
};
    
static_assert( sizeof(Header) == 2 && alignof(Header) == 1, "alignment vital");


// --- usage ---
int main(){
    // Header may be placed into memory where it overlaps only one byte;
    // in that case, it's .zFmt and .wFmt members are never read or written to
    char buffer[1];
    Header * header = new (buffer) Header;

    // can I be sure (or statically assert) that these instructions
    // will only read and write to the nearest (and only) owned byte?
    header->xFmt = 0;
    header->yFmt = 0;
    header->xFmt += 1; 
    header->yFmt += 1; 
}
```

Side notes:

The algorithm currently works, but I want to make sure it doesn't rely on undefined behavior.  I believe strict-aliasing is adhered to by using placement new, but maybe that assumption is incorrect?

Also, I want to use this structure and bit-fields, in this way... because they look nice!  Not the best reason haha, so if this isn't possible, my fallback is to interpret the bytes without a structure, as `uint8_t` with shifts and masks.  I'm also aware I could perform slicing using inheritance, which I'll research if this is undefined.

Comment: This is going to confuse other people if they ever work with your code.  Possibly even you, if you come back to it much later.  At work, we have to maintain code from as far back as 2000, some of which is not changed for years at a time.

Comment: @DaveS - oh for sure.  I wouldn't subject others to this, it's just one of many pranks on future me

Comment: @DaveS as far back as 2000. You lucky <expletive deleted>!

Comment: Do you plan to be serializing this compressed data beyond your program? There are general compatibility concerns that should be considered when relying on bit-fields. Even if the data is being sent to/from storage, your same program compiled with a different compiler can have its bit-fields packed differently.

Comment: This will certainly have problems if your compiler's bit-field allocation unit is not single bytes, though I *think* your static assert should catch that case.

Comment: @paddy - no, it never leaves the program, it's strictly to help reduce memory bandwidth when rendering 3D geometry.

Comment: @DaveS • My code base at work goes back to 1988.  I feel your pain.

Comment: This is all undefined behavior, so there are no guarantees of **any** kind.  What sort of answer could possibly be useful here?

Comment: @DavisHerring: The asker seems unsure whether it is UB, so if you are convinced that it is, then an answer explaining why would be very useful.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It seems uselessly obvious that an object can’t be created in insufficient storage, but I can’t immediately find any actual wording to that effect (better than a [note](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#22)) so as to provide a useful [language-lawyer] answer.

Comment: This kind of hack is sometimes seen in C programs to fake a derived struct.  In C++ you actually *have* derived structs, and that seems like the right way to do what you want.

Comment: @DavisHerring - I've found a copy of the standard and found a rather surprising answer, in terms of language lawyering.  I've posted it as an answer if you'd like to review it.

Comment: @DavisHerring _It seems uselessly obvious that an object can’t be created in insufficient storage_ It can, but its lifetime won't start https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#1.1

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, since I believe I've found the answer in a 2020 edition of the C++ ISO standard (bolding the relevant parts):

> - **A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having
>   nonzero width.** [Note: Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might involve
>   additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation.
>   — end note] **Two or more threads of execution (6.9.2) can access separate memory locations without interfering
>   with each other.**

> - [Note: Thus a bit-field and an adjacent non-bit-field are in separate memory locations, and therefore can be
>   concurrently updated by two threads of execution without interference. **The same applies to two bit-fields,
>   if one is declared inside a nested struct declaration and the other is not, or if the two are separated by a
>   zero-length bit-field declaration, or if they are separated by a non-bit-field declaration.** It is not safe to
>   concurrently update two bit-fields in the same struct if all fields between them are also bit-fields of nonzero
>   width. — end note]

```
struct {
    char a;
    int b:5,
    c:11,
    :0,
    d:8;
    struct {int ee:8;} e;
}
```

> - [Example: A class declared as [the above] contains four separate memory locations: The member a and bit-fields d and e.ee are each separate memory
>   locations, and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields b and c
>   together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields b and c cannot be concurrently modified, but
>   b and a, for example, can be. — end example]

The note about "two or more threads of execution" accessing separate memory locations, leads me to believe the following:

- Accessing `yFmt` can't cause an observable side-effect.  As pointed out by Nate's comment, it's possible for the compiled code to still load and store to where it thinks `zFmt` lives, while upholding this requirement.  But if the access must be atomic and preserve the previous value, (and so long as the program owns this memory), then there's only one behavior that's possible.  (As for the program owning the memory, so long as the atomic instruction works on memory aligned more granularly than the program can own memory, which I believe is the case, then I'm comfortable assuming I can't cause an access violation in this way.)

Along with the rule that all members and bit-fields of a structure must have an increasing address, I believe this makes my usage well-defined, with the following change:

```
struct Header {
    uint8_t xFmt : 4;
    uint8_t yFmt : 4;
    uint8_t :0;
    uint8_t zFmt : 4; // must not be read/written when header is mapped to 1 byte
    uint8_t wFmt : 4; // must not be read/written when header is mapped to 1 byte
};

static_assert( sizeof(Header) == 2 && alignof(Header) == 1, "");
```

Not saying it's not prone to causing programmer mistakes of course, but I'm fairly convinced this is well-defined, at least for the time being.

Comment: I'm not so convinced.  This means that another thread concurrently accessing `zFmt` and/or `wFmt` will not cause a data race.  That's not the same as saying that this thread doesn't access `zFmt, wFmt` at all.  For instance, this thread could access `xFmt` using a word-size atomic read-modify-write that also accesses `zFmt` but is guaranteed not to change its value.

Comment: This all assumes that you've have a valid `Header` object to begin with, which would require the placement new to be valid when the storage is less than the object requires. Which I highly doubt is ok.